# Add Protocol to Custom Menus

Tags: menus, filters, wp-kses

I've been using `tel:` links in Custom Menus combined with Responsive Design to add a "Call Now" button to my themes for smartphones. It's been working well. A client just asked me to also add a "Send Text" button. I thought I would use `sms:` which seems to have passable device support.

However, WordPress is stripping it out of the URL when I save the menu. After research, I concluded it has something to do with `esc_url()` and/or `wp_kses()` (see [Trac ticket #18268](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18268)). I concocted the following code in an effort to add the SMS protocol myself and put in it functions.php:

```
<?php
function add_new_protocol() {
    global $protocols;
    $new_protocols = array( 'sms' );

    return array_merge( $protocols, $new_protocols );
}
add_filter('pre_kses', 'add_new_protocol');
?>
```

It didn't work :) This was a bit of a shot in the dark; I'm still pretty green at using filters etc. I would love a pointer on the correct method for adding new protocols to Wordpress for use in Custom Menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `kses_allowed_protocols` filter:

```
function wpse_allow_sms_protocol( $protocols ) {
    $protocols[] = 'sms';
    return $protocols;
}

add_filter( 'kses_allowed_protocols', 'wpse_allow_sms_protocol' );
```